# Modern/Online SharePoint Choice field not allowing update of choices

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, choice-field, update, conditional

I was unable to update a choice field for a list in modern SharePoint (online). In addition to the bigger problem described below in the table (for anyone interested), I could not change the name of this list either. Tried changing from “Course Catalogue” to “Course Inventory”, on list view page. An edit box opens, it allows to save, but name switches back to ‘…Catalogue’. I changed it in list settings and there it shows correctly as “Inventory” but not where the list is used. The issue faced in three different areas is described in table below. I tried multiple times, even closing the page and trying again but no success. And old MS community forum listed this as an unfixable glitch.
[MS Office Forum - closed/unsolved](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-custom-column-choices-not-updating/7220ab96-f29a-491b-a298-1108d2b88fe1)

I found a solution finally which I'll share in solutions. Again, the table below is optional. Sharing in case it helps others detect their own issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd sent the issue to our M365 team to report to Microsoft. When they reviewed my site, the list name showed correctly updated. The support person mentioned that the URL will continue to have old list name which was used at creation. He suggested it was probably a caching issue and he'd monitor the Choice field issues.

When I got back to the list after the weekend and after one reboot I saw the 'hybrid' choice correctly showing in dropdown. The remaining two choices which I had deleted and tried to enter again were now showing in the edit pane in a pending state without color. I was able to give them color and update color of an existing choice. So, the solution seems to be to clear cache or try a computer reboot.